# Why doesn't Files.newInputStream(path) support the available method on FIFOs?

Tags: java, linux, file-io, inputstream

Take this simple test class:

```
public class InputStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[100];
        Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
        System.out.println("File " + path);

        try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))) {
//      try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
            System.out.println("Available: " + is.available());
            System.out.print("First 100 bytes: '");
            is.read(buf);
            System.out.write(buf);
            System.out.println("'");
        }
    }
}
```

This takes a filename/path on the command line and simply prints out the result of `available()` on the corresponding `InputStream` and up to<sup>1</sup> the first 100 bytes from the stream.

It works fine, even when you pass it redirected command output (which internally will create a FIFO and pass it as the file argument). For example, running it as:

```
java InputStreamTest <(echo -n "ABC")
```

... results in the following output:

```
File /dev/fd/63:
Available: 3
First 100 bytes: 'ABC'
```

Looks good so far. Now, uncomment the line that uses the new-and-recommended-Java-7-ish `Files.newInputStream(path)` to create the `InputStream` and comment our the prior line which uses the oldschool `FileInputStream` class. Now it fails:

```
File /dev/fd/63
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Illegal seek
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:264)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.available(ChannelInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
    at net.tdowns.compression.InputStreamTest.main(InputStreamTest.java:20)
```

Evidently the `available()` method on the stream is failing. Now you might just say "hey, don't call `available()` it is pretty much useless". Unfortunately, a class as core as `BufferedInputStream` uses it! If you comment out the direct call to `available()`, this *still* fails:

```
File /dev/fd/63
First 100 bytes: 'Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Illegal seek
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:264)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.available(ChannelInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:353)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at net.tdowns.compression.InputStreamTest.main(InputStreamTest.java:22)
```

So you are in a pretty tough spot - if you use `Files.newInputStream(path)`, the `available()` call might fail, and you can't really avoid use of this call since other JDK stream classes themselves like to call it.

Any way out?

---

<sup>1</sup> I say *up to* because of course the `read()` method may return fewer than the requested number of bytes, even if more are available. In practice, it doesn't do that for files and for fifos you get at least a few K, so this will *usually* print out 100 bytes if 100 bytes are available.